# Array of 1 couple of integers

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary

I would like to have an array (or a vector) and at each position I would like to store a couple of integers like this.

```
(1, 999)
(15, 1000)
(19, 1897)
etc..
```

Now I know I can have a list of maps, but I feel it is an overkill.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use `pair<int, int>` here as the `vector<T>` element.  This allows you

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vector;
```

It's bit more usable with a typedef.

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> intPair;
...
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vector;
vector.push_back(intPair(1, 999));
vector.push_back(intPair(15, 1000));
```

Answer (score 4):

In c++11 you can use [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) to do this as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::tuple<int, int> > intPairs;
    intPairs.emplace_back(1, 999);
    intPairs.emplace_back(15, 1000);
    intPairs.emplace_back(19, 1897);
    std::cout << std::get < 0 > (intPairs[0]) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, you can do this:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pairs = {
   {1, 999},
   {15, 100}, 
   {19, 187},
   {29, 177},
   //and so on
};
```

In C++03, you've to manually add each pair to the vector using `push_back()` as @JaredPar explained in his answer, or you can use `insert()` if you want to insert it at specific *position* in the vector.

Answer (score 1):

Use a std::pair< int, int > as your elements in the array.